# File is not under 'rootDir' in Cypress tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, react-native, configuration, cypress

I'm trying to configure Cypress in my Project.  I bumped into a problem with the typescript configuration for Cypress and I need your help!
This is how my project looks like:

```
fronend/
    - cypress/
        -tsconfig.json
    - src/
    - tsconfig.json
    - package.json
    - cypreess.json
```

This is my tsconfig.json from Cypress directory:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": [],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress"],
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "composite": true
  }
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json file from frontend directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.svg"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "scripts"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./cypress/"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Cypress can work fine without `"extends": "../tsconfig.json"` but I need it because I would like to export files from src directory in my cypress ts files.

Can you please give me ideas about what is wrong with my configurations?
I would prefer to do not to change the main tsconfig.json file because it runs our UI.
This is my error:

```
File '/**/fronend/cypress/support/objects/client.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/**/frontend/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via '../../support/client' from file '/**/frontend/cypress/integration/EndToEndTests.spec.ts'
    Matched by include pattern './**/*.ts' in '/**/frontend/cypress/tsconfig.json'ts(6059)
tsconfig.json(3, 15): File is matched by include pattern specified here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the fact that the entirety of the `cypress` folder is not contained under `src`. When setting the `cypress/tsconfig.json` file, you can override the `rootDir` property set in the parent `tsconfig.json` file.

Try setting that field to the cypress directory.

```json
...
"compilerOptions: {
    "rootDir": "./"
    ...
},
...
```

^ The above may work, since the `tsconfig` is within the `cypress` directory.

Comment: Thanks! It helped!

Comment: Should it be in .src in the first place rather that fixing it by changing rootDir? I have the same issue and don't really want to change rootDir. Please let me know.